# Jenkins Pipeline - Build with parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to execute an already defined job using **build** method with jenkins pipeline.
This is a simple example:

```
 build('jenkins-test-project-build', param1 : 'some-value')
```

But when I try to execute it I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got [{param1=some-value}, jenkins-test-project-build]
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:442)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:380)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:156)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:126)
...............
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are getting this error, because you didn't pass the name of the attribute which should store 'jenkins-test-project-build'.

In your case you should pass **job** attribute.

```
build(job: 'jenkins-test-project-build', param1 : 'some-value')
```

Here are the list of available options([pipeline-build-step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)):

- job
- parameters (optional)
- propagate (optional)
- quietPeriod (optional)
- wait (optional)

Comment: As @Zoodor says below the parameters should be described as follows: `build job: 'jenkins-test-project-build', parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value:"some-value"), string(name: 'param2', value:"some-value")]`

Answer (score 16):

You have multiple issues in your build call.

First, as sshepel mentionned it you should **name your parameters** if you have more than one (you can forget to name it only if you only use the default parameter `job`, e.g. `build 'my-simple-job-without-params'`).

The second problem is that you are **not passing parameters correctly**. To pass parameters to a downstream job, you should use the parameter named `parameters` and give it an array of objects that define each of your parameters, e.g. :

```
build job: 'jenkins-test-project-build', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: "some-value" ]]
```

Also, note that parenthesis are optional in a Groovy method call.

Comment: Yes indeed .. I found that problem after solving the first one :D Thank you for your answer

Comment: I had to use a slightly different syntax to get the parameter passing to work for me: `build job: 'jenkins-test-project-build', parameters: [string(name: 'param1', value:"some-value")]`

Comment: How can we pass choice parameter

Comment: @RamakrishnaYelduti If your child pipeline has `choice` parameters, then you can use the `string` argument in the parent pipeline.

Comment: Also, if there are multiple parameters to pass, the nesting is important. It looks like this.... parameters: [[ ...parameter... ],[ ...parameter... ],[ ...parameter... ]]

Answer (score 2):

Use the pipeline code generator of the specific jenkins server to generate the code, in my case this was happening because of version mismatch, we use a different version for development then production and each used a different syntax to call a job and pass parameters.